# jQuery onhide event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I'm hiding my elements using `.hide();`.

Is there an evert handler that is fired when I hide something?  You see, I have a bunch of elements in my code, and I'm hiding them or showing them (using jQuery) a bunch of times.  To keep things in check, in an efficient way, I would love to use an event handler for `.hide()`

Could someone point me in the right direction for this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You can provide a callback for hide() if you want, but I don't think this is what you are looking for. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no `onhide` event, its a custom method from jQuery which uses animations to create a "hiding" effect on the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a callback function

```
$('#element').hide('slow', hideCallback);

$('#element').show('slow', showCallback);

function hideCallback()
{
    // You can do your stuff here
}

function showCallback()
{
    // You can do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Isn't `$('#element').hide('slow', myCallback)` much simpler?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('p').on('ohWowIGotHidden', function(){
    document.write('O look, it works');
});

$('p').hide(function(){
    $(this).trigger('ohWowIGotHidden');
});
```

​You can create a custom event and trigger it whenever you call the hide method..

Answer (score 1):

You can override hide in jquery to dispatch an event after calling the original function.